# Thread-Safe implementation of Volley Requests with a JSON Array feed

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-volley

I am not sure if this is the right approach to the following problem:

I have to record some GPS Data and store it in a JSON Array. This data is to be sent to the server to be stored in a database. The server is capable of handling a JSON Array of any length. The relevant code is:

```
            public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
            try{
                JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();

                temp.put("trackerid", prefs.getString("trackerid", "Some ID"));
                temp.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
                temp.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
                Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
                Date currentLocalTime = time.getTime();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-d hh:m:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                temp.put("timestamp",sdf.format(currentLocalTime));
                arrJ.put(temp);
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                log("Not able to format JSON" + ": "+ e.toString());
            }
              StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                   @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //Code that verifies if the request is successfull and removes only the sent objects from the JSONArray. 
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                           //Code that Handles the error.
                        }
                    }){
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                            try {
                                params.put("data", json.put("data", arrJ).toString());
                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                                return params;
                        }
                    };
                    queue.add(sr);

        }
```

The problem I am facing is as follows: Once the GPSData has been recorded in the JSONArray, It is then picked up by the Network(Volley) Request thread and processed. Now because I don't know how long the request would take, I need to be able to get the sent Parameters in the `getParams()` function in the `onResponse()` function to be able to remove only the sent objects from the JSONArray to avoid duplication.

I am not sure if this is the correct implementation. If there is a better approach, I am definitely open to incorporating it into the app.

Comment: why are you using a new Thread in Here? If you are using volley it will handle the Thread. You dont have to care about the thread.

Comment: Alright. Sure I'll edit the question.

Comment: Do you have access to the server code? may be you can send the timestamp as response .So that you can remove the corresponding row from the arraylist or map.

Comment: Yeah. I do. I was looking for solving the issue without having to edit it. But I guess there isn't a better solution

Comment: What is the response right now?

Comment: HTTP Status code 200.

Comment: And you are sending multiple locations at once?

Comment: Yes. I am. As this depends on the user's speed, data is being recorded every 5 meters. So unless he has a stellar internet connection,multiple points are being sent

Comment: Would you mind to do a dirty workaround for this? I mean a client side workaround?

Comment: Absolutely not. Any solution is good at this point.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: You will need to maintain 2 lists for this purpose, or have the server return the trackerid successfully uploaded in the response.

Comment: @Krish, yep just checked. It works. Really appreciate the time you put into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this custom request ,

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author Krish
 */

public class CustomRequest {

    private Response.Listener<String> mOriginalListner;
    private String requestData;
    private StringRequest request;

    public CustomRequest(int method, String json, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this.requestData = json;
        this.mOriginalListner = listener;
        init(method, url, mListener, errorListener);
    }

    private Response.Listener<String> mListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            mOriginalListner.onResponse(requestData);
        }
    };


    private void init(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this.request = new StringRequest(method, url, listener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    params.put("data", requestData);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return params;
            }
        };
    }


    public StringRequest build() {
        return request;
    }


}
```

and you can use the response to remove the send objects.